# how to tell if my C program was invoked via shebang?

Tags: shell, argv, shebang, argc

I've built a little command interpreter (in C++) which can be invoked either directly, or in a script via shebang (#!).  It can take arguments on the command line (which appear as argc/argv in my code).

Trouble is, when invoked via shebang, the script itself gets passed to my program as argument 1.  That's problematic; I don't want my command interpreter trying to process the script that it was invoked from.  But I can't see any easy way to tell when this is the case.

EDIT: As an example, if I have a script called "test" which starts with #!/usr/local/bin/miniscript, and then invoke it as *./test --help -c -foo*, I get 5 arguments in my C code: /usr/local/bin/miniscript, ./test, --help, -c, and -foo.  If I invoke it directly, then I get four arguments: /usr/local/bin/miniscript, --help, -c, and -foo

How can I tell when my program was invoked via a shebang, or otherwise know to skip the argument that represents the script it was invoked by?

Comment: I'm not sure about the actual answer, but is it possible to check the name of the script within the script itself, compare it to the first argument, and skip it if they're the same?

Comment: I don't actually have any other way to get the name of the script.  So I understand why the Unix gods decided to pass it as an argument.  But I don't see how that helps me in this case.

Comment: What C code do you have that starts with a shebang? I don't follow you there...

Comment: No, the C code starts with int main(int argc, const char * argv[]), as command-line C programs do.  As such it can be invoked directly on the command line, OR it can be invoked from a script that starts with a shebang followed by the path to the C program, as in "#!/usr/local/bin/miniscript" (where miniscript is my compiled C program).  Sorry I was unclear.

Comment: ...if you're writing an interpreter, you should expect a script name as an argument. Do you have a first argument that doesn't follow syntax to be an option (f/e, doesn't start with a `-`)? Then treat it as a name, same as python/perl/sh/every other interpreter does. (And if you see a bare `-` as the first argument, take that as an instruction to read your script text from stdin)

Comment: If `myscript` has a `#!/bin/sh` shebang, *that script's users have a reasonable expectation* that they can run `/bin/sh ./myscript`. If you tried to do some kind of magic that wouldn't let someone run `/usr/local/bin/miniscript yourscript` as an equivalent to `./yourscript` when that script has a shebang of `#!/usr/local/bin/miniscript`, that would be creating a bunch of confusion for your users, and with what benefit?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, ...incidentally, `tcc` *can* be used as a shebang for C code (to compile and run it inline). Not that that's what the OP is trying to do here, though. :)

Comment: Ah, I see my confusion — I thought a program invoked via shebang also received the rest of that invoking script via stdin.  Apparently it does not.  My program is already behaving correctly, and I just didn't realize it!

Answer (score 0):

My question was based on a wrong assumption.  I believed that two things were happening when a program was invoked via shebang:

1. Path to that program was passed as the first argument.
2. Contents of that program were piped to stdin.

So I was essentially worried about processing the content twice.  But only item 1 is true; item 2 does not happen (as pointed out by helpful commenters on my question).  So if the C code accepts the name of a file to process as a first argument, and ignores any initial line starting with a shebang, then all is right with the world.